# Reading the frequency of an AC signal using an arduino

Tags: arduino, analog, ac, signal, frequency

Basically I have a motor with a magnet spinning on the end. I have a sensor that produces an AC signal when the spinning magnet is placed next to it. It produces a voltage of ±300mV. I want to measure the frequency of the signals, so I can calculate the speed of the motor. I want this to be fed back/processed to an arduino so I can display the reading on a screen. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: What are the ranges of speeds of the motor?

Comment: In my experience once-per-rev type magnet sensors can produce vastly different amplitudes and shapes at max speed and minimum speed so ditto @angelatlarge comments

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to being the signal into a counter/timer channel of the microprocessor. Configure the counter/timer to operate in counter mode. If you can count the pulses for a set interval of say one second would give you a reading of pulses/second from the motor.

There will sometimes be a situation where waiting one second is intolerable because you need the speed update more often. In some cases you can reduce the interval of pulse counting to a 100 msec period.

In other cases it may be more suitable to use the timer/counter in timer mode so that it can be used to measure the duration of the input pulses. This would then need to be computationally inverted to turn duration into equivalent pulse speed.

Comment: If you're doing this you need an amplifier (opamp, comparator or single transistor) to generate good logic levels from the 300mV sensor signal. I think it's the best way, but a (poor) alternative would be to use an analog input on the AVR processor, and perform level detection and zero crossing detection in software. That uses much more CPU power, unnecessarily.

Comment: The AVR has an analog comparator that could be suitable. It can trigger the timer and everything.

Comment: The second way that Brian Drummond mentioned was the method that my tutor recommended. Can i just plug the AC signal directly into the analog channel and use the arduino analogue to digital convertor to read these points where it crosses? I have read that an AC signal can damage an arduino. Basically I wouldn't mind using the second way suggest if it meant using no extra components as there is restricted space in the case where the arduino is going. Angelatlarge the speeds will be a maximum of about 2500 rpm. Michael Karas I'll have a look at using the counter/timer, is it just an a digital in

Comment: What about using a diode bridge to rectify the volatge and then plug in to an analogue input of the arduino and set a  threshold to measure each peak of the volatge?