# Measuring the frequency of a 120v variable frequency drive with arduino/pic

Tags: arduino, frequency-measurement

Riffing off of this post-- [Reading the frequency of an AC signal using an arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67613/reading-the-frequency-of-an-ac-signal-using-an-arduino)

I'd like to use an arduino (not committed to a model, and would also like to have the ability to consider PIC/rasberry pi/Rabbit in the future) to measure the frequency of a 120v variable frequency drive in the realm of 30Hz-80Hz of an analog signal. My AC supply 9-12V is powered the VFD to bring the voltage down followed by a bridge rectifier and a regulator to power the arduino and also perform the measurement.

1. I'm confused about prepping the signal. This is two fold. The variable frequency drive uses PWM and a 16k switching frequency. Can I assume that some of the 16K PWM noise will be lopped off by the transformer or do I need to make some kind of filter so that I'm not getting "false positives"?
2. What kind of input(s) do i feed the signal into for the counting/measuring? Analog, Counter? Please explain the considerations and why.
3. Can I use a voltage divider followed by a rectifier to lower the lower the voltage and send it to an analog input and just count the rising edge?
4. Since I have control over the amplitude and is there any reason for op-amps? When I've seen this in similar examples most of them assume a much smaller amplitude. If the amplitude is within operating range of the input is there any reason that you can't go directly to an analog input?
5. Do i care that arduino can't measure negative voltages? Unclear if this means it cannot register a - waveform or if I need to make sure a negative voltage doesn't pass through to one of the pins.
6. Do I need to implement a form of hysteresis or is this unnecessary?

Comment: Most commercial VFDs have a frequency analog output. Does yours? Concerns with this approach are noise and harmonics on the voltage fed to the transformer which may lead to saturation and overheating. Using one of double the primary voltage rating may help. I would reckon that some hysteresis is required to prevent false triggering by noise.

Comment: My VFD does not have an analog output.